# Getting the file extension of an image

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'm modifying an AppleScript I found online for uploading images to Imgur. I'm having difficulty extracting the file extension though--despite what I've found online, nothing seems to work.

I'm trying to set a variable to the file extension (i.e. ".png", ".jpg", etc.) with the quotes around them.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder"
        -- convert file paths to posix
        set imagePath to POSIX path of (input as text)
        -- debug display dialog imagePath as text with title "Path of File" buttons {"Okay"} default button "Okay"

        --debug display dialog input as text with title "Input"
        set ext to name extension of input

        set apiKey to "26ff5c40cbedf50e7f81124ab473c1cc"
        set curlCommand to "curl -F \"key=" & apiKey & "\" -F \"image=@" & imagePath & "\" http://api.imgur.com/2/upload"
        set answer to do shell script curlCommand
        set atid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "<imgur_page>"
        set link to text item 2 of answer
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "<"
        set link to text item 1 of link & (ext as text) --will be a direct link to the file, but the extension of the original file will matter
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to atid
        set the clipboard to link
        display notification "URL copied to clipboard" subtitle "Upload to Imgur complete"
    end tell
end run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
set ext to name extension of input
```

Try using:

```
set ext to (last text item of input)
```

This should define `ext` as the last text item after `.` in `input`

Comment: After doing that, `ext` is saved as `Macintosh HD:Users:username:Dropbox:Pictures:funny_pics:zpaIq7S.gif`, as opposed to just ".gif".

Comment: @Nxt3, what is the value of `input` and `parameters`?

Comment: Not sure. Originally, the code [looked like this](https://gist.github.com/imkmf/3445912); but I modified it to only accept a single image and removed it opening in the browser.

Comment: This script will be run upon right-clicking an image file in Finder.

Comment: @Nxt3: Ah, okay... try using `set ext to "." & (name extension of last item of input)` instead.